# Bounds for a parameter-dependent quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quadratic-forms

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a symmetric matrix, $x(t)\in\mathbb{R}^n$, and $t\in\mathbb{R}^+$. I'm interested in finding upper and lower bounds for the following quadratic form
$$ f(x(t)) = x(t)^{\intercal}A x(t)$$
assuming that $\Vert x(t) \Vert \leq \beta$, $\beta\in\mathbb{R}^+$. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: The lower and upper bound are the same as for $x^TAx$ where $\|x\|\le \beta$ i.e. $\lambda_\min(A) \,\beta$ and $\lambda_\max (A)\,\beta$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc can you please elaborate a bit more? This result is actually useful. Many thanks.

Comment: Sorry, the upper bound is$\lambda_{\max(A)}\beta^2.$ The lower bound is $\lambda_{\min(A)}\inf_t\|x(t)\|^2.$ I will post the answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any symmetric matrix $A$ there holds $$\lambda_{\max(A)}= \max\{x^TAx\,: \,\|x\|\le 1\}, \quad \lambda_{\min(A)}= \min\{x^TAx\,: \,\|x\|\le 1\}$$
[(see part hessian)](https://%5Clambda_%7B%5Cmax(A)%7D=%20%5Cmax%5C%7Bx%5ETAx%5C,:%20%5C,%5C%7Cx%5C%7C=1%5C%7D)
Therefore by homogeneity $$ \lambda_{\min(A)}\|x\|^2\le x^TAx\le \lambda_{\max(A)}\|x\|^2$$ i.e.
$$ \lambda_{\min(A)}\|x(t)\|^2\le x(t)^TAx(t)\le \lambda_{\max(A)}\|x(t)\|^2\qquad (*)$$
Thus $$\sup \{x(t)^TAx(t)\,:\,\|x(t)\|\le \beta\}\le \lambda_{\max(A)}\sup_t\|x(t)\|^2\le \lambda_{\max(A)}\beta^2$$ Moreover the equality occurs when $x(t)\equiv \beta\, v_{\max(A)}$, where $v_{\max(A)}$ is the unit eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda_{\max(A)}.$

By $(*)$ we get
$$\inf_t x(t)^TAx(t)\ge \lambda_{\min(A)}\inf_t\|x(t)\|^2$$
The equality occurs when $x(t)=\|x(t)\|\,v_{\min},$ where $v_{\min}$ denotes the unit eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda_{\min(A)}$. The bound is equal $0$ if $\|x(t)\|$ is not bounded away from $0.$

Comment: This is very clear. Many thanks!